# Merging Data into a Word Document

Tags: merge

I have a text file that is created from a pdf or some document with data, such as : 
"RUN_DATE","RM","RD","RY","RUN_ID","RUN_MONTH", etc.....
"05/09/2014","05","09", etc.....

I now want to take all this information and merge it into a word document that is already set up with these fields. I know I can do this by using the merging feature in Microsoft Word, but say I have a section in which I was merging in a list of certain items. If every single text file had the same number of items in the list, I can create the word template before hand and then merge the items, but what if I have a different number of items each time? Is there a way I can code to insert as many lines as needed in the word document before merging? Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own mail merge solution in .NET by using [Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854(v=office.15).aspx). This involves learning Open XML specification and some work around the implementation. You didn't told us what your environment/platform/technology is, but if you can use Office COM you can use it instead of Open XML SDK. Also take a look at [this](http://www.docentric.com) mail merge toolkit for .NET. It might be the solution you are looking for.